# How to get current timestamp with CQL while using Command Line?

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cql, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to insert into my CQL table from the command line. I am able to insert everything. But I am wondering if I have a timestamp column, then how can I insert into timestamp column from the command line? Basically, I want to insert current timestamp whenever I am inserting into my CQL table -

Currently, I am hardcoding the timestamp whenever I am inserting into my below CQL table -

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (ID TEXT, NAME TEXT, VALUE TEXT, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (ID));

INSERT INTO TEST (ID, NAME, VALUE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) VALUES ('1', 'elephant',  'SOME_VALUE', 1382655211694);
```

Is there any way to get the current timestamp using some predefined functions in CQL so that while inserting into above table, I can use that method to get the current timestamp and then insert into above table?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can use the timeuuid functions `now()` and `dateof()` (or in later versions of Cassandra, `toTimestamp()`), e.g.,

```
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, NAME, VALUE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)
                  VALUES ('2', 'elephant',  'SOME_VALUE', dateof(now()));
```

The `now` function takes no arguments and generates a new unique timeuuid (at the time where the statement using it is executed). The `dateOf` function takes a timeuuid argument and extracts the embedded timestamp. (Taken from the CQL documentation on [timeuuid functions](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#timeuuidFun)).

## Cassandra >= 2.2.0-rc2

`dateof()` was deprecated in Cassandra 2.2.0-rc2. For later versions you should replace its use with `toTimestamp()`, as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (ID, NAME, VALUE, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE)
                  VALUES ('2', 'elephant',  'SOME_VALUE', toTimestamp(now()));
```

Comment: @lorcan: I might also be using timeuuid functions in my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602979/how-to-retrieve-only-the-information-that-got-changed-from-cassandra).. Can you help me on my question as I believe you might be able to help me on my question..

Comment: how to change default timestamp...timestamp always comes with timezone in cassandra..but I don't want timezone in timestamp..so I want to change the default format..is there anyway to change?

Comment: perfect! just the kind of function I was looking for.

Comment: My local machine timezone is IST, however, the timestamp takes UTC timezone and stores the value. what could be wrong?

Answer (score 17):

In new version of `cassandra` could use `toTimestamp(now())`, and note that function `dateof` is **deprecated**.

e.g

```
insert into dummy(id, name, size, create_date) values (1, 'Eric', 12, toTimestamp(now()));
```

Comment: "In new(er) version(s) of Cassandra" — what version is that? 3.0 or was that supported in 2.x already?

Comment: @AlexisWilke `toTimestamp()` is supported in 3.0 for sure, but it seems it's since 2.2, you can check: https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/2015/12/18/5-things-you-need-to-know-about-cassandra-2-2/

Comment: toTimestamp() function is not available in cassandra version 2.1.8 atleast. I just verified.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 2 different ways for different purposes to insert the current timestamp. From the [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/upsertTimestamp.html):

> Inserting the current timestamp
>
> Use functions to insert the current
>   date into date or timestamp fields as follows:
>
> Current date and time
>   into timestamp field: `toTimestamp(now())` sets the timestamp to the
>   current time of the coordinator.
>
> Current date (midnight) into
>   timestamp field: `toTimestamp(toDate(now()))` sets the timestamp to the
>   current date beginning of day (midnight).