# How to insert time series data into Cassandra

Tags: insert, cassandra, cql

I have created the following table, but now want to insert the data in things list which i could not because CQL want me to specify the Event time. I dont have that but yes I have OrderId .

What's best way to handle this situation ?

CREATE TABLE "Orders_By_Time" 
(OrderId text, 
EventTime timestamp,
ThingsList list,
PRIMARY KEY (OrderId, EventTime) ) 
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (EventTime DESC);

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

When you insert data you need to specify all parts of the primary key, so you can use dateof(now()) to generate a timestamp for the current time.

See this similar question:

[How to get current timestamp with CQL while using Command Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623432/how-to-get-current-timestamp-with-cql-while-using-command-line)

Comment: Hey Jim, Yes sure I can enter the record with dateof(now). But what I want is to update the record like, add entries in ThingsList across that OrderId.

For example I have already entered a record. But now I want to enter the thingslist for that orderId later.
I only know the order Id for that time series entry but not the timestamp of that entry. 

Please suggest what is better solution may be i need to change the data model to achieve this

Comment: Then you probably wouldn't want EventTime as part of your primary key, it would just be a regular column.  The way you've defined your table is as a time series, but with a time series you are usually recording events over time and not updating those events later.  If you need both a time series and a way to update it later, you could have two tables, orders_by_time and orders_by_orderid, with the ThingsList being in the orders_by_orderid table with just orderid as the primary key.